# Keras - How to use argmax for predictions

Tags: python, numpy, keras, argmax

I have 3 categories of classes `Tree, Stump, Ground`. I've made a list for these categories:

```
CATEGORIES = ["Tree", "Stump", "Ground"]
```

When i print my prediction, it gives me the output of

```
[[0. 1. 0.]]
```

I've read up about numpy's Argmax but I'm not entirely sure how to use it in this case.

I've tried using

```
print(np.argmax(prediction))
```

But that gives me the output of `1`. That's great but I would like to find out what's the index of `1` and then print out the Category instead of the highest value.

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

CATEGORIES = ["Tree", "Stump", "Ground"]


def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 150 # This value must be the same as the value in Part1
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

# Able to load a .model, .h3, .chibai and even .dog
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("models/test.model")

prediction = model.predict([prepare('image.jpg')])
print("Predictions:")
print(prediction)
print(np.argmax(prediction))
```

I expect my prediction to show me:

```
Predictions:
[[0. 1. 0.]]
Stump
```

Thanks for reading :) I appreciate any help at all.

Comment: You just have to index your CATEGORIES list with the results of np.argmax

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro THANKS! that really worked. can u reply as an answer? So I could tick u

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to index categories with the result of `np.argmax`:

```
pred_name = CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction)]
print(pred_name)
```

Comment: Could you tell me how is the array ordered? why it's not ["Stump", "Tree", "Ground"]? Thanks